# Trigger needs dbms_alert declared

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, trigger, permissions

A trigger has given me the following:

```
 ORA-04098: trigger 'adminuser.DB_ERROR_CHANGE_TRIG' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

and this is when working on altering schemas/triggers/etc from an import of a client database.

I ran

```
show errors trigger adminuser.db_error_change_trig
```

and the results were:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/5      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
2/5      PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_ALERT' must be declared
```

Now, googling, I have found that I need to grant explicit execute privileges to the public user which I did with

```
grant execute on dms_public to public
```

However, this has not worked.
How can I determine what is going on, as well as how to fix this.  Thirdly, is dbms_alert schema specific? Meaning, my understanding is the the full name of the object is SYS.dbms_alert, is there another for another schema or is one global one?

Comment: Privileges received through roles are not in effect in PL/SQL code. You need to grant the execute privilege directly to the owner of the trigger

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be missing synonym for dbms_alert for adminuser schema. A object grant and synonym both are normally required (unless you own the object).

Try following as sys account, perhaps it will fix the problem.

`create or replace synonym adminuser.dbms_alert for sys.dbms_alert;`

If you don't want to create a synonym, you should use sys.dbms_alert, if your create a synonym as shown above, using just dbms_alert is sufficient in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `public` is a **user** and not a **role**? Privileges acquired via roles have no effect in PL/SQL context. You need to grant sufficient permissions for sys.dbms_alert to the **user**.

Answer (score -2):

Grant execute on DBMS_ALERT to public;

Comment: Thanks for the possibly useful answer. It might be even more helpful if you could describe why this works and how it would help.