# Oracle 12: Using compound trigger to update data in same table on each insert/update

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I need some help fixing the code of a compound trigger.
I have a table with two columns that are used for auditing (upd_by and upd_time) and I'm trying to create a trigger that would update these columns on each insert/update to the table.

The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_info(
    id NUMBER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_upd_by VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    last_upd_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I found some examples on using compound triggers, and this is the code I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER customer_info_trg
    FOR UPDATE OR INSERT ON custommer_info
    COMPOUND TRIGGER
    TYPE r_customer_info_type IS RECORD (
        id   custommer_info.id%TYPE
    );

    TYPE t_customer_info_type IS TABLE OF r_customer_info_type
        INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

    t_customer_info   t_customer_info_type;

    AFTER EACH ROW IS BEGIN
        t_customer_info (t_customer_info.COUNT + 1).id := :NEW.id;
    END AFTER EACH ROW;

    AFTER EACH STATEMENT IS BEGIN
        FOR indx IN 1 .. t_customer_info.COUNT
        LOOP
            UPDATE customer_info
            SET last_upd_by = USER, last_upd_time = SYSTIMESTAMP
            WHERE id = t_customer_info (indx).id;
        END LOOP;
    END AFTER EACH STATEMENT;
END;
```

But when I run update on the table I get `ORA-04098: trigger 'customer_info_trg'k is invalid and failed re-validation`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger needs dbms\_alert declared](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51389/trigger-needs-dbms-alert-declared)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a compound trigger. Use simply

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER customer_info_trg
    BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON custommer_info
    FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN
    :NEW.last_upd_by := USER;
    :NEW.last_upd_time := SYSTIMESTAMP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to use a regular trigger instead, but was getting a different error and  found a solution to that is to use the compound trigger.